# How to implement custom GridLayoutManager for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, android-motionlayout

How to implement custom LayoutManager for RecyclerView with similar (but yet, very different) behavior as GridLayoutManager? *(see picture)*

[image]

Am I able to use (or extend) GridLayoutManager with `spanCount: 2` and `orientation: HORIZONTAL` for this and just alter behavior by overriding some methods?

I need to change order and also position of items so the result will look like on right part of image.

I already achieved same result programatically, by adding `"Bubble" Views` as childs into `FrameLayout` and then setting their `LayoutParams.leftMargin` and `LayoutParams.TopMargin` accordingly.

The problem now is that I am using `MotionLayout`, because I also need scroll-based animations on this grid and I also need to use `RecyclerView`, because this grid can have size around 40 items.